# Connect Java application using Tomcat to database

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, web, server

I follow this tutorial (https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/connect-db.html) but for a server it uses GlassFish while I am using Tomcat.
How do I connect my MySQL database to my java web application?
I mention that I use NetBeans 8.2 as IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Generally is a good idea to create a connection pool and using it to access the database.

Using tomcat you can use the pool offered by tomcat, you can follow the [official guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)